# TLP settings being ignored

Tags: power-management, 17.04, thinkpad, tlp

I have my `/etc/default/tlp` set so that, when on battery, the CPU will scale between 30% and 60%. Running `tlp-stat -p` (output below), I can see those settings are being recognized. However, the actual CPU ranges shown are 1170MHz and 2340MHz. Why is this?

```
--- TLP 1.0 --------------------------------------------

+++ Processor
CPU model      = Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7600U CPU @ 2.80GHz

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1170000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2340000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1170000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2340000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1170000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2340000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1170000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2340000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct      =  30 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct      =  60 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo          =   1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct         =  34 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates       =  36

x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu0                            = powersave
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu1                            = powersave
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu2                            = powersave
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu3                            = powersave

/sys/module/workqueue/parameters/power_efficient       = Y
/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog                          = 0

+++ Undervolting
PHC kernel not available.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your processor is shown as Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7600U CPU @ 2.80GHz, which has a maximum turbo frequency of 3.90 GHz. Since turbo is enabled, 3.90 GHz equals the 100% CPU frequency and:

3.90 * 60% = 2.34 GHz.
3.90 * 30% = 1.17 GHz.

Comment: D'oh! Thank you. For some reason I forgot that the percentage applies to the turbo freq.